# Nodes status still DOWN after servers restart

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-stack

I have a swarm cluster containing **4** nodes : **1** Manager + **3** Workers

When restarting one worker'server, its status becomes **"DOWN"** when running :

```
docker node ls
```

Also already deployed services shutdown in this node (containers exited), and cannot restart it.
I have tried to :

- recreate cluster after each reboot (too ugly and doesn't resolve the problem )
- deleting the heavy file `/var/lib/docker/swarm/worker/tasks.db` (doesn't improve the situation)
- simply waiting (but it still down after hours)

I m using docker **18.09ce**

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you have to do.

1. Update node availability ( Run command from manager node)

   docker node update <> --availability active
2. If still issue persists then try to do following things.

   // Add worker again to swarm using token previously generated.
3. If still not solve then you might to do following thing Remove all nodes from cluster.

   docker swarm init --force-new-cluster // Use with care.

   [Recover docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/swarm/admin_guide/#recover-from-disaster)